# CoreDNS do not respect local DNS

Tags: kubernetes, dnsmasq, coredns, k3s

I am running a k3s cluster on some raspberry pi 4, in my local network. I have a DNS server (dnsmasq) on the master nodes. I want that the pods of my cluster use that DNS server, via coredns. However when I ping an adress from within a pod I always pass via the google DNS servers and overpass my local DNS rules.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        hosts /etc/coredns/NodeHosts {
          reload 1s
          fallthrough
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

this is my coredns config. As you see there is the `forward . /etc/resolv.conf`

my /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain home
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Where is this file  /etc/resolv.conf from? Pod or host?

Comment: this file is frome host

Answer (score 4):

thanks guys I change my coredns to

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        hosts /etc/coredns/NodeHosts {
          reload 1s
          fallthrough
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . <master node ip>
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
  NodeHosts: |
    <master node ip> master
    <slave node ip> slave
```

and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

You might try just forwarding to the Master node's real IP where your DNS server is running.  This would be the IP that can be utilized by the other nodes in the cluster.  So rather than /etc/resolv.conf, it would be something like:

`forward . <master node ip>`

Answer (score 1):

[CoreDNS official doc](https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/) says that:

> In its most basic form, a simple forwarder uses this syntax:
>
> `forward FROM TO...`
>
> `FROM` is the base domain to match for the request to be forwarded.
>
> `TO…` are the destination endpoints to forward to. The `TO` syntax allows you to specify a protocol, tls://9.9.9.9 or dns:// (or no protocol) for plain DNS. The number of upstreams is limited to 15.

Somehow instead of destination endpoints which are capable of performing DNS resolution, you are forwarding to the localhosts /etc/resolv.conf (which is a valid approach), where you have `loop` IP.

If you really need DNS requests to be processed not by CoreDNS **Pod** but by DNSMasq on the Host **Node** , the easiet way would be to forward them to Node's IP.

Comment: If i forward the master node ip, would it be still possible to use the internal kubernetes dns ? Like would it be still possible to ping service.namespace from a pods ?